# Java - Making ArrayList Values Rotate for Game

Tags: java, libgdx, rotation

I have three global variables:

```
private PhysicsActor blade;
private PhysicsActor blades;
private ArrayList<PhysicsActors> blades;
```

I created an actor object from a class I created for my game.

```
blade = new PhysicsActor();
        blade.storeAnimation( "", exTex );
        blade.setOriginCenter();
        blade.setEllipseBoundary();
        blade.setMaxSpeed(50);
        blade.setDeceleration(50);

    bladesList = new ArrayList<PhysicsActor>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            float xCoord = randomFloatGenerator(425, 50);
            float yCoord = randomFloatGenerator(mapHeight - 200, 275);
            blades = blade.clone();
            blades.setPosition(xCoord, yCoord);
            mainStage.addActor(blades);
            bladesList.add(blades);
        }
```

The problem is not that they do not spawn. It is that when I call for them to rotate while my game is running in my update(float dt) method, only one of them is rotating:

```
public void update(float dt) 
{   
    // rotate the blade 70 degrees
    blades.rotateBy(70); 

    // rest of code etc
}
```

[Here is an image to help visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TNv9.png)

I know that this is happening because I am only rotating the ***blades*** actor. What I want to do is have them all rotate from the ArrayList. I do not know how to get them from the list however. I have tried bladesList.get(i) using a for loop and a couple other ways I saw online but it would not work. Any tips or instructions for me?

Also, I will post more code to clarify anything confusing if requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
for (PhysicsActor blade : bladesList) {
    blade.rotateBy(70);
}
```

this will make all the blades in your list rotate by 70. Given you can access the array from where you are calling it.

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly as I wanted. I completely forgot about being able to use for loops this way. Thank you so much!